# Viewing condition coverage in intellij

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit, code-coverage, jacoco

Given the code:

```
public void foo(int age,boolean smart) {
  if (age>18 && smart) { // <--- This is the part that should be covered
    doSomething()
  }
}
```

Using JUnit I test foo(15,true) and foo(25,true)

IntelliJ will report that the condition line was fully covered (green), but it was **not**.

In Eclipse using Jacoco the line is correctly labeled as partially covered, and the condition is colored yellow.

Is there a way for IntelliJ to give coverage at the condition level?

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+Coverage+Runner

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. If you're using the IntelliJ IDEA coverage runner, you need to switch it to tracing mode.

Comment: Great, I was under the impression that the branch was already covered in Sampling. I have to now go back to check few of my 100% code covered tests :D

Comment: This worked fine for me to. I was relying on the analysis made by SonarQube for this info. Now I can get the info locally also. Thanks.

Comment: In the newer IDE versions, the option seems to have changed, it's now known as "Enable branch coverage and test tracking".

Answer (score 1):

As a reference where to find the setting in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 (I didn't find it that easily, I was expecting it to be a global setting)
[image]